# Model not defined

Tags: python, django

I defined a Question model with a description and a foreign key.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        verbose_name="User",
        default=None
    )

    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=60,
        #verbose_name=_("Description"),
    )
```

After that, I ran the migrations.

Then, in `views.py` I created a method which accesses objects of this model:

```
def own_questions(request):
    questions = Question.objects()
    return JsonResponse(questions)
```

The problem is that when I access the URL `/questions` corresponding to this method, I get:

```
NameError at /questions/
global name 'Question' is not defined
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `Questions` in your views.py:

```
from app.models import Question
```

Also, `questions = Question.objects` only give you the queryset manager and you can't call that, instead for all questions, you need:

```
questions = Question.objects.all()
```

**Edit:**

I shouldn't assume what you are trying to query from model `Question`, so here's django doc about [how to write ORM for queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/).

Comment: Given that the method was own_questions, I'm guessing the OP actually wants Question.objects.filter(user=request.user) (with probably some extra code to handle non-logged in users)

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you haven't imported

`from .models import Question`

into your `views.py`